# How can you modify interactively a shell script during the debugging?

Tags: bash, shell

While debugging a bash shell script I saw a mistake I have done in some part of my code. This mistake can be a variable name, a variable value or generally line(s) of code.

Is it possible to correct it while running the debugging mode? Or the only option is to exit the debug mode, correct the mistake(s) and rerun the debugging process? It would be very helpful if such an option of correcting mistakes "on the fly" exists. Especially for scripts that require long running times and you have to repeat the whole run process from the beginning multiple times (if there are many mistakes).

For example:

```
#!/bin/bash

 set -x # debugging 
 trap read debug

 a="1" # wrong value, should be 2 
 b="5"
 sum=$(bc <<< "$a + $b")  

 set +x
```

The above script has a trap to execute one line of code at a time and continues to the next line after pressing enter.
During the debugging suppose that I realize that a=1 but should be something else lets say a=2. The next command b=5, is not executed yet because of the trap, so I was thinking of something like inserting a=2 just below a=1 and then proceed with enter to continue the debugging.

Something like in the code below:

```
#!/bin/bash

 set -x # debugging 
 trap read debug

 a="1" # wrong value, should be 2 
 a="2" # <-This is the value that a should have
 b="5"
 sum=$(bc <<< "$a + $b")  

 set +x
```

This approach does not work, I guess because the whole script is called only in the beginning of the run. What would be a good way to handle such an issue in shell scripting?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just flesh out your parser a bit:

```
#!/bin/bash

function parser {
    IFS= read -r input
    printf "Going to do: >%s\n" $input
    eval "$input"
}

set -x # debugging 
trap "parser" debug

a="1" 
b="5"
sum=$(bc <<< "$a + $b")  
set +x
```

This of course only works with one liners, but should get you started. When you see the debug is on `a=1` (you will see it on screen) you can just type `a=3` and `return`. Hit `return` on all other lines - you'll see the effect at the `sum`.

Note in this method (overriding after you see the line in debug) you always run **AFTER** the faulty command ran, since that's when the debugger outputs it. If you want to see the command before running use

```
echo $BASH_COMMAND
```

in your parser. Of course, running `a=10` before  `a=1` ran is somewhat counter-productive.

An improvement for example may be to turn off debugging while parsing, and skipping the echo if no input is received:

```
function parser {
    set +x
    IFS= read -r input
    if ! [ -z "$input" ]; then
        printf "Going to do: >%s\n" $input
        eval "$input"
    fi
    set -x
}
```

Note this won't modify the script itself. To modify the script itself you would need to add a `sed` command as well to actually modify the script, or perhaps echo each line to a new file, replacing with new input in debug if received - **this is the safer option**. This can be done as so (note the parser runs after the line already ran, so we always output the previous command, and override it if needed):

```
set prev_cmd="#!/bin/bash"
function parser {
    set +x
    IFS= read -r input
    if ! [ -z "$input" ]; then
        printf "Going to do: >%s\n" $input
        eval "$input"
        prev_cmd=$input
    fi
    echo $prev_cmd >> debug_log.bash
    prev_cmd=$BASH_COMMAND
    set -x
}
```

You imagination is the limit here. And the syntax. I would move your parser to a separate file and source it on demand as well.

**Answers to questions in comments in order**

1. Note I have `echo $prev_cmd >> debug_log.bash`. `prev_command` will be empty on the first call to the parser if you don't set it before. As the shebang for sure was never debugged and so won't be in your new file, it's a good initial choice for a first line to be dumped to the new file - which needs it anyway. You could of course set it empty or to some comment, whatever you prefer.
2. When you enter the debugging function debug is turned on (by definition). In order to prevent debugging in the debugger, I shut it off. Finally when leaving the function I need to re-activate it so debugging will continue. That's why the order is 'reversed' to the file - it shuts off your initial activation, and re-activates before continuing.
3. If you want to stop debugging before `sum=...`, put `set +x` before - that's what shuts off debug. Just like I did in the parser.

**Acknowledgements**: Special thanks to Charles Duffy for making the code safer to use. and just better.

Comment: Could you elaborate on what the `set prev_cmd="#!/bin/bash" ` does?

Comment: I also noticed that the sequence of  `set -x` and `set +x` that is used to enclose the area of the debugging is reversed inside the function parser (of your 2nd example) but I don't understand why.

Comment: Finally I would like to ask how someone ( while using the 2nd or 3rd approach you provided) can enclose part of the script to be debugged and corrected. So suppose that below the command `sum=$(bc <<< "$a + $b")  ` are other lines of code and I want to enclose for the debugging the code up to the sum variable. Thank you @kabanus for the very helpful answer

Comment: @dinosthanellas Hey Dinos, that, quite a bit, Ill edit in your questions in the answer.

Comment: `eval $foo` and `eval "$foo"` are not identical, and you almost certainly want the latter. Compare with `printf -v tab '\t'; foo="printf '${tab}%s\\n' 'hello world' 'goodbye world'"` -- `eval $foo` prints spaces, whereas `eval "$foo"` prints actual tabs.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Thanks, you are most certainly correct.

Comment: (I'd also suggest `IFS= read -r input` -- otherwise you're losing literal backslashes in the input, as well as leading and trailing whitespace).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy You're really taking my answer to the next level, I was just drafting this up quickly. I suggest go over it completely then I'll incorporate all of your good suggestions.

Comment: ...well -- the bigger issue with this approach here is that it won't handle things that aren't self-contained lines. If you're starting a block -- `if`, `for`, `case`, etc -- that can't be `eval`ed on its own. Unfortunately, I'm not sure what options are really available to fix that, if any.

Comment: In terms of tactical as opposed to strategic suggestions, though, I'd suggest switching from `echo $foo` to `printf '%s\n' "$foo"`; see APPLICATION USAGE and RATIONALE in http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/echo.html re: the reasons to use printf, and http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#echo_.24foo re: the quotes